# How can I design storage that conforms to the standard's implementation of std::any?

Tags: c++, c++14, stdany

The standard working draft (n4582, 20.6.3, p.552) states the following suggestion for implementations of `std::any`:

> Implementations should avoid the use of dynamically allocated memory for a small contained object. [ Example: where the object constructed is holding only an int. —end example ] Such small-object optimization shall only be applied to types T for which is_nothrow_move_constructible_v is true.

As far as I know, `std::any` can be easily implemented through type erasure/virtual functions and dynamically allocated memory.

How can `std::any` avoid dynamic allocation and still destroy such values if no compile time information is known at the time of destruction; how would a solution that follows the standard's suggestion be designed?

---

If anyone wants to see a possible implementation of the non-dynamic part, I've posted one on Code Review: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/128011/an-implementation-of-a-static-any-type

It's a little too long for an answer here. It's based on the suggestions of Kerrek SB on the comments below.

Comment: Maybe use a `union`?

Comment: @KerrekSB I understand the premise behind small object optimizations (such as SSO for `std::string`). However, I can't see how a destructor could be called without knowing the type.

Comment: @user2296177: the private, type-erased derived class is something like `Impl<T>`; if you know that `sizeof(Impl<T>)` doesn't exceed `sizeof(any)` (plus maybe an extra word or so), then you can construct `Impl<T>` in-place in the object itself. You don't need to allocate memory dynamically in order to create objects dynamically.

Comment: @KerrekSB I assume you mean using something like `std::aligned_storage_t`, but I still need to manually call the destructor, and I can only do that by knowing what type is stored there. Could you please post an example?

Comment: You know the type when the contained value is set. Save the destructor in a `std::function` member variable that you call when the `any` is destructed.

Comment: @user2296177: The destructor is part of the type erasure, right? You just call `ptr()->~Base()`.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, `any` takes anything and dynamically allocates a new object from it:

```
struct any {
    placeholder* place;

    template <class T>
    any(T const& value) {
        place = new holder<T>(value);
    }

    ~any() {
        delete place;
    }
};
```

We use the fact that `placeholder` is polymorphic to handle all of our operations - destruction, cast, etc. But now we want to avoid allocation, which means we avoid all the nice things that polymorphism gives us - and need to reimplement them. To start with, we'll have some union:

```
union Storage {
    placeholder* ptr;
    std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(ptr), sizeof(ptr)> buffer;
};
```

where we have some `template <class T> is_small_object { ... }` to decide whether or not we're doing `ptr = new holder<T>(value)` or `new (&buffer) T(value)`. But construction isn't the only thing we have to do - we also have to do destruction and type info retrieval, which look different depending on which case we're in. Either we're doing `delete ptr` or we're doing `static_cast<T*>(&buffer)->~T();`, the latter of which depends on keeping track of `T`!

So we introduce our own vtable-like thing. Our `any` will then hold onto:

```
enum Op { OP_DESTROY, OP_TYPE_INFO };
void (*vtable)(Op, Storage&, const std::type_info* );
Storage storage;
```

You could instead create a new function pointer for each op, but there are probably several other ops that I'm missing here (e.g. `OP_CLONE`, which might call for changing the passed-in argument to be a `union`...) and you don't want to just bloat your `any` size with a bunch of function pointers. This way we lose a tiny bit of performance in exchange for a big difference in size.

On construction, we then populate both the `storage` and the `vtable`:

```
template <class T,
          class dT = std::decay_t<T>,
          class V = VTable<dT>,
          class = std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same<dT, any>::value>>
any(T&& value)
: vtable(V::vtable)
, storage(V::create(std::forward<T>(value))
{ }
```

where our `VTable` types are something like:

```
template <class T>
struct PolymorphicVTable {
    template <class U>
    static Storage create(U&& value) {
        Storage s;
        s.ptr = new holder<T>(std::forward<U>(value));
        return s;
    }

    static void vtable(Op op, Storage& storage, const std::type_info* ti) {
        placeholder* p = storage.ptr;

        switch (op) {
        case OP_TYPE_INFO:
            ti = &typeid(T);
            break;
        case OP_DESTROY:
            delete p;
            break;
        }
    }
};

template <class T>
struct InternalVTable {
    template <class U>
    static Storage create(U&& value) {
        Storage s;
        new (&s.buffer) T(std::forward<U>(value));
        return s;
    }

    static void vtable(Op op, Storage& storage, const std::type_info* ti) {
        auto p = static_cast<T*>(&storage.buffer);

        switch (op) {
        case OP_TYPE_INFO:
            ti = &typeid(T);
            break;
        case OP_DESTROY:
            p->~T();
            break;
        }
    }
};

template <class T>
using VTable = std::conditional_t<sizeof(T) <= 8 && std::is_nothrow_move_constructible<T>::value,
                   InternalVTable<T>,
                   PolymorphicVTable<T>>;
```

and then we just use that vtable to implement our various operations. Like:

```
~any() {
    vtable(OP_DESTROY, storage, nullptr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can std::any avoid dynamic allocation and still destroy such
>   values if no compile time information is known at the time of
>   destruction

That seems like a loaded question. The latest [draft](http://eel.is/c++draft/any.class) requires this constructor:

```
template <class ValueType> any(ValueType &&value);
```

I can't think of why you need to have "type erasure" unless you want code to handle both small *and* large cases at the same time. But then why not have something like this?<sup>1</sup>

```
template <typename T>
  struct IsSmallObject : ...type_traits...
```

- Small objects: use [placement new](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage) and explicit destructor calls.
- Large object: use an [allocator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Allocator)

In the former case, you can have a pointer to your uninitialized storage:

```
union storage
{
    void* ptr;
    typename std::aligned_storage<3 * sizeof(void*), 
                std::alignment_of<void*>::value>::type buffer;
};
```

Using a union as [@KerrekSB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37094710/how-can-i-design-storage-that-conforms-to-the-standards-implementation-of-std#comment61733126_37094710) suggested.

Notice that the type is not needed to be known for the storage class. Using some kind of handle/dispatch (not sure about the real name of the idiom) system it becomes trivial at this point.

First let's tackle what destructing would look like:

```
  template <typename T>
  struct SmallHandler
  {
    // ...

    static void destroy(any & bye)
    {
        T & value = *static_cast<T *>(static_cast<void*>(&bye.storage.buffer));
        value.~T();
        this.handle = nullptr;
    }

    // ...
   };
```

Then the `any` class:

```
// Note, we don't need to know `T` here!
class any
{
  // ...

  void clear() _NOEXCEPT
  {
    if (handle) this->call(destroy);
  }

  // ...
  template <class>
  friend struct SmallHandler;
};
```

Here we factor out the logic that needs to know the compile-time type to a handler/dispatch system, while the bulk of the `any` class only has to deal with RTTI.

---

<sup>1</sup>: Here's the conditions I would check for:

1. `nothrow_move_constructible`
2. `sizeof(T) <= sizeof(storage)`. In my case this is `3 * sizeof(void*)`
3. `alignof(T) <= alignof(storage)`. In my case this is `std::alignment_of<void*>::value`

Answer (score -1):

Inspired by [boost any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/boost/any.hpp) I came up with this [(test it on ideone)](http://ideone.com/OoyZSq) (I created a minimal case to show how to destroy a type erased container like `any` without dynamic memory. I focused only on constructor/destructor, omitting everything else, ignoring move semantics and other things)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

struct A { ~A() { cout << "~A" << endl; }};
struct B { ~B() { cout << "~B" << endl; }};

struct Base_holder {
  virtual ~Base_holder() {}
};

template <class T>
struct Holder : Base_holder {
  T value_;

  Holder(T val) : value_{val} {}
};

struct Any {  
  std::aligned_storage_t<64> buffer_;
  Base_holder* p_;

  template <class T>
  Any(T val)
  {
    p_ = new (&buffer_) Holder<T>{val};
  }

  ~Any()
  {
    p_->~Base_holder();
  }
};

auto main() -> int
{  
  Any a(A{});
  Any b(B{});

  cout << "--- Now we exit main ---" << endl;
}
```

The output:

```
~A
~A
~B
~B
--- Now we exit main ---
~B
~A
```

Of course the first one are temporaries being destroyed the last two prove that destruction of `Any` calls the right destructor.

The trick is to have polymorphism. That's why we have `Base_holder` and `Holder`. We initialize them via placement new in a `std::aligned_storage` and we explicitly call the destructor.

This is just to prove you can call the right destructor without knowing the type held by `Any`. Of course in a real implementation you would have an union for this or a pointer to a dynamically allocated memory and a boolean telling you which one you have.

Comment: @Barry of course. That's why you would actually have an union. For this and for a dynamically allocated memory.

Comment: Strictly speaking, `static_cast<Base_holder*>(static_cast<void*>(&buffer_))` is UB.  The "pointer-to-structure is a pointer to its first subobject" is guaranteed only for standard-layout types, which `Holder<T>` is not.

Comment: @BenVoigt the casts has nothing to do with subobject as far as I know. I used `buffer_` as a storage for `Holder`. I construct with placement new into it, and then I call the destructor via the base class `Base_holder` and I use pointers to have polymorphism. I am not that familiar with the standard, but it looks ok to me.

Comment: @BenVoigt should I post a question about this specific matter?

Comment: @bolov: You use placement `new` to construct a `Holder<T>`, which ought to be aligned at the beginning of `buffer_`.  But later you create a pointer to `Base_holder` without performing the appropriate upcast.  There's no guarantee that the `Base_holder` subobject starts at the first byte of the `Holder<T>` object (the Standard explicitly defines when such a guarantee is made -- for objects with standard-layout type -- and `Holder<T>` is not standard-layout).

Comment: @BenVoigt I see what you are saying. Ty, I am very happy to learn this. I think I came up with a solution. Would you please check the edited post to see if it is ok? Basically I now have a `Base_holder` pointer.

Comment: This should at least `static_assert` that you have enough space. On a typical 64-bit system, the vtable pointer itself takes up 8 bytes.

Comment: @T.C. the point was to illustrate the concept. Of course you would have to check if it fits and if `T` is `no_throw_move_constructible`

Comment: @bolov: Yes, that's a very simple method for fixing the problem.  It does take up extra storage, but I haven't been able to think of a good way to avoid that.  I guess it should be possible to have just one pointer (to a template-produced static deleter function) rather than a pointer and a v-table.