# Does std::any employ type erasure, sub-typing, or polymorphism?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, type-erasure, boost-any, subtyping

While reading the documentation on [boost any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/any/reference.html) and [experimental any](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/any),
I did not see any mention of [type erasure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_erasure).

I'm trying to understand the concept of "type erasure" as it applies to C++.

Is it correct to say that the "any" type uses "type erasure" when storing its values?
Is it correct to say that it uses "polymorphism" when storing its values?
Is "type erasure" a kind of "polymorphism"?

The wikipedia article on [polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)), also does not mention "type erasure".
It mentions "subtyping".  Is "type erasure" a kind of "subtyping"?

Sorry if this question seems headed in different directions.

To summarize,

**How does "type erasure", "polymorphsim", and "subtyping" relate to the *any* type in C++?**

Comment: Some info: 1) [2 Blog posts](https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2013/11/18/type-erasure-part-i/); 2) [Stack Overflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450159/type-erasure-techniques)

Comment: You can use inheritance-based polymorphism as a technique for implementing type erasure. Sean Parent covers such a technique in his "Inheritance is the Base Class of Evil" talk. That's not to say it's the only option.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it correct to say that the "any" type uses "type erasure" when storing its values?

Maybe I and other people have a different definition of "type erasure", but *using* type erasure to implement `any` doesn't make any sense to me. If we use the definition ["represent a variety of types through a single generic interface"](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Type_Erasure), then `any`, `std::function`, etc. fit the bill. The [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_erasure) definition "ensuring that the run-time execution of a program does not depend on type information" doesn't make any sense in the context of C++. Generics (the archetypal example of type erasure) doesn't mean "remove types from the language". Also, `std::any` (optionally) uses RTTI. So I would look elsewhere than wikipedia.

> Is it correct to say that it uses "polymorphism" when storing its values?

Polymorphism is one way of implementing `any`. It's not required by any means, though. As far as I can tell, only Boost uses polymorphism. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37101152/6335390).

[boost](https://github.com/boostorg/any/blob/develop/include/boost/any.hpp)

Other implementations show that it's not required:

[libc++](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/experimental/any)

[libstdc++](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc++-v3/include/experimental/any)

Also see [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/128011/an-implementation-of-a-static-any-type) and the accompanying [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37094710/6335390)

> Is "type erasure" a kind of "polymorphism"?

No. Do you consider templates, generics, and `std::function` to all be polymorphism?

Comment: In the context of C++, "type erasure" has a different meaning than what you quote from Wikipedia. See https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Type_Erasure for example.

Comment: @interjay The quote I used is from that page actually. The wikipedia link is from OP's question.

Comment: OK, then OP's link is not relevant to C++. By the way, Boost's implementation does use (dynamic) polymorphism. Just search for "virtual". And as far as I can see, none of the implementations require RTTI, except to implement the `type()` function.

Comment: @interjay `any_cast`? I added that it's optional.

Comment: "Do you consider templates, generics, and std::function to all be polymorphism?".  I don't know.  I have heard people refer to templates as compile time polymorphism before.